# How can I find the value of a property in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, properties

How can I find the value of the same property in different objects in Javascript only using property?

Example:

```
var o={
    y:'efgh',
    x:'abcd'
};
var m={
    x:'abcd'
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the properties with dot or bracket notation.

```
o.x;
o['x']; // or
```

For bracket notation, you can declare the property before use.

```
var prop = 'x';
o[prop];
```

If you have an array of objects you can loop through the array.

```
var arr = [{ x: 'abcd' }, { x: 'lkjh' }]

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var val = arr[i].x; 
    var val2 = arr[i]['x']; // or
    alert(val + " " + val2);
}
```

If you need to check if the property exists you can use

```
typeof arr[0].y !== 'undefined';
```

or

```
arr[0].hasOwnProperty('y');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.` to get the value of a property. For eg. `o.y` in your case will return `'efgh'`

Answer (score 0):

use the following :

```
//set up example from question
var o={
    y:'efgh',
    x:'abcd'
};
var m={
    x:'abcd'
};

//access property in objects by name
var prop = 'x';
var x_of_o = o[prop];
var x_of_m = m[prop];
```